# AutoMapper Map Int

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper and it works perfectly except for int properties, as it just replaces the field with 0

Code:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int E1 { get; set; }
    public int E2 { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, Employee>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

Employee e1 = new Employee {E1 = 7};
Employee e2 = new Employee {E2 = 78};

Mapper.Map(e2, e1);
```

> //Results //E1 = 0, E2 = 78.... Does it supposed to only map E2 and
>   leave E1 as i did not initialized it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto mapper seems to set zero to un-initialized integer properties. So your see the destination object's E1 is zero(0). E2 has been correctly mapped.

I tried with setting the AutoMapper to ignore the un-initialized property which gives me the desired result.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee { E1 = 7 };
            Employee e2 = new Employee { E2 = 78 };

            Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, Employee>().ForMember(x => x.E1, x => x.Ignore());
            var de1 = Mapper.Map<Employee, Employee>(e2, e1);

            //de1.E1 is 7.               

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# `integers` are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) / numerical structs. Each value type has an implicit default constructor that initializes the default value of that type. The default value for `integers` is `zero`. So even if you don't explicitly initialize them in your code the default constructor will set it to zero.

So with this information the property values of your employees are:

**e1** {
E1 = 7, 
E2 = 0
}

**e2** {
E1 = 0, 
E2 = 78
}

Now when you map **e2** to **e1** (is this done deliberately?) **e1** will become:

**e1** {
E1 = 0, 
E2 = 78
}

So your code works perfectly fine. Because value types can never be null unless they are boxed, your condition will always return true.